# How to limit number of downloaded (parsed) entries (items) in ROME Fetcher

Tags: java, rss, feed, atom-feed, rome

I am using `ROME` & `ROME Fetcher` for getting Feeds (`ATOM/RSS`) in my `JavaEE` web application.

In some cases I would like to limit number of downloaded/parsed entries/items. I want to avoid this scenario: get all and ten just make `subList()`.

Any ideas or anybody solved this somehow ?

Thanks.

- [Rome](https://github.com/rometools/rome)
- [Rome Fetcher](https://github.com/rometools/rome-fetcher)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a feasible way that you could download just a few of them - at the end of the day you send a request to the server and it will decide what to send you.

To me this sounds a bit like premature optimization. Dependent on what you're building, it might be better to do something like caching data if you're worried about performance.

Anyhow, I can't see anyway you can do this with ROME, but it could be done if you built your own XML parser.

Comment: We were using our own parser, but it was not perfect (to support all versions of RSS/ATOM). If user clicks on UI in content, request to our backend to get feed from remote host. Content owners do not want all feed items to be shown.Our testers noticed significant JVM memory increase during getting whole feed - therefore we only want to get that amount of feed entries that UI request. For now we downloaded all and then returned only that amount UI wanted, but this is not good for performance - as our web app has many hits, just imagine many users just clicking on links to show RSS feed in UI.

Comment: Have you tried caching the data? Assuming you only have a set number of RSS feeds to check you can hold the data for x minutes in memory before having to send requests again/process the data again. This isn't hard to implement and I did this exact method myself at work for an RSS feed that was being hit every time a user used our service.

Comment: I know what are you talking about, we also using browser caching for that, but I would rather also dig more in getting feed and limit it there. this is only my thought...

Comment: This would likely have more of a difference than a browser cache. It would stop your server from having to process it multiple times for any users, not just ones that already cache it.

It shouldn't be too hard to make your own RSS reader that also works with Atom if you have a little time. I've done it myself and it was very easy.

Comment: to create own parser needs time, i could do that, but this is the reason i'm using Rome -> time.. and i think its good library

Comment: In that case you could easily modify ROME to allow you to only parse a few of the posts. Although I would still look at server side caching rather than just client side